# Ctrl+C key combination doesn't work

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

On my Windows 8.1 laptop <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does NOT work. I am able to copy using right click or using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd>. The other key combinations like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> etc. all work.

Note that my <kbd>C</kbd> key also does work.

Comment: Does using the right control key and C work?

Answer (score 1):

Is this issue for all applications, e.g. Notepad, WordPad, etc? If not, then the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> combination might be in use in just one particular application.

Another possibility is that some other application is hijacking that key combination. To test that, restart in Safe mode, with startup applications disabled. Test <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> in Notepad. If it then works correctly, restart normally and use [SysInternals Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to find processes that hijack keystrokes. Use Task Manager to selectively kill suspect processes.

Finally, Nirsoft's [ShortcutsMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shman.html) lists Desktop and Start Menu shortcuts, and their [HotKeyList](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/hot_keys_list.html) shows registered shortcuts (though, regrettably, not the app registering them).